# Using Django Bad Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm new in Django and Rest Framework and I didn't find how to do that:

Filter an endpoint request without argument to return Bad Request. Example:
`get_foo/?foo_id=`

Return:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

At this time, a get request without argument gives all the values from the database. It's a big DB, so I have to do this filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter it so If you have an empty queryset you will get that response:

```
If foo_id == '' # or If not foo_id 
    return Response(
    {"res": "Bad Request"},    
    status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
else:
    return . . .
```

In your resposne you can also put your text

```
If foo_id == '' # or If not foo_id 
    return Response({
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request"})
```

Comment: At views.py, right? I'm using class-based

Comment: Yes, wherever you are making the filtering. I assume that would be in your `get` function of your `DRF views`.